# How do you call the line y=0?

Tags: geometry, terminology

What do you call the line y=0 in a 2-dimensional plot? It's not the x-Axis, since i have the x-Axis below the plot. Is it called zero line?

Comment: What do you mean by saying, "I have the x-axis below the plot"? Unless you adopt a different convention, it is standard to set y=0 to be the x-axis.

Comment: It's the $x$-axis.

Comment: @Clayton the ticks and the tick labels are at the bottom of the plot, which is at y=-0.25. I thought this was the x-Axis?!

Comment: It's the $\,x-$axis *exactly*

Comment: You plot it wrong i think. $y=0$ is the axis of $x$

Comment: The x-axis is defined as the line $y=0$. Similarly, the y-axis is defined as the line $x=0$.

Comment: I believe what @kutschkem is after is to avoid confusion, as the auxillary line that helps the spectator of his plots to keep track of $x$-coordinates is not placed at its customary place. Whether it is the customary place or the ruler itself that is referred to as the $x$-axis is not something I would brush off as trivial. Whichever it is, what do you call the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the spirit of Arthur's comment:

> I believe what @kutschkem is after is to avoid confusion, as the auxillary line that helps the spectator of his plots to keep track of x-coordinates is not placed at its customary place. Whether it is the customary place or the ruler itself that is referred to as the x-axis is not something I would brush off as trivial. Whichever it is, what do you call the other?

To avoid confusion in such a scenario, you can simply refer to the line $y = 0$ exactly as that: $$\text{"the line}\;y = 0.\text{"}$$

I would not, however, refer to the line, in your case, $y = -0.25$ as the $x$-axis. That term is "too loaded". Again, if you need to reference that auxiliary line ruling the plane, refer to it as the line $y = -0.25$.

Customarily, the $x$ axis is defined as the line $y = 0$, and the $y$-axis as the line $x = 0$, but whatever the case, you are safe in referring to the line in question as $y = 0$.